# Why are fixed effects in DiD model reasonable?

Tags: fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

While I was looking into the difference-in-differences (DiD) approach, I found many posts commenting that beyond ordinary calculations, the model should control for unit and time fixed effects.

Suppose:

$$y_{} = \beta_0 + \beta_1Treat + \beta_2After + \beta_3(Treat \times After)$$

Why should the above fixed effects be controlled for in addition?

Would this mean the same as:

$$y_{} = \beta_0 + \beta_1community + \beta_2Year + \beta_3(Treat \times After)$$

Edit:

I am investigating the impact of a policy change in the area of wind energy taxation at the municipal level, i.e., panel data. In a classic DiD procedure, both the municipal level and the time level would be captured in terms of `treat` and `after`, respectively. As far as I have correctly understood others in this forum, despite using first equation, I should additionally control for entity and time fixed effects.

So, in my case, I would use a two way fixed effects, in which I would additionally control for community and year. Why do I have to or should I do this? For the DiD approach, the control on single effects, in this case `Treat` and `After`, is crucial. Wouldn't the two way fixed effects model cancel out these influences?

Comment: Do you want to know why we adjust for "group" and "time" in these models, or whether the two models produce similar results given the different representations of "fixed effects"? Please provide further clarity, if possible.

Comment: Hello Thomas, 

I have added to my question above. I am new here and currently working on my master thesis. Therefore I apologize for any misunderstanding. I know that this question may have been asked several times before, but I had problems understanding the content of the answers. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have a better understanding now. Why does your second equation include state fixed effects? Do you mean community fixed effects?

Comment: State was only one example here. Correctly, it should of course be community-fixed effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why should the above fixed effects be controlled for in addition?

If by the above "fixed effects" you mean those of unit *and* time, then no you do not necessarily need to adjust for them simultaneously with $Treat$ and $After$. In fact, assuming the policy is uniformly adopted by treated municipalities in the same year, then the first equation will work just fine.

In your next question you ask whether the former equation "means the same as" the latter equation with community and year fixed effects. First, you need to be very clear about your panel level identifier. We are assuming "unit", "entity", and "community" fixed effects all mean the same thing; they may, or may not. Going forward, I will assume you have a panel of "communities" and you observe them over time (i.e., years), though "municipal community" seems more apt in my estimation.

Earlier, I noted that if this taxation policy is introduced in all treated communities at the same time, then you can proceed with either equation; they produce equivalent estimates of $\beta_3$. On the other hand, if the policy is adopted within different communities in *different years*, then you must proceed with the latter equation. That sort of answers the "why" of your question. In a setting where the timing of the policy is not standardized, then we cannot say any one treated group starts (or ends) treatment at any one time. You may, in fact, have many different groups with different adoption years! In that setting, two-way fixed effects is the way to go.

> For the DiD approach, the control on single effects, in this case $Treat$ and $After$, is crucial. Wouldn't the two way fixed effects model cancel out these influences?

Assuming you have a simple setting with a policy administered in the same year, then you correctly note that the constituent elements of the product term will not remain. The community fixed effects will absorb $Treat$. Consider that the community effects adjust for the stable characteristics of those communities. One of those time-constant factors is communities' membership to the treatment group; you're either in it, or you're not. Similarly, the year fixed effects will absorb $After$. The year effects adjust for those common shocks affecting all communities. That's similar to controlling for "time" with a pre-/post-policy indicator variable. Remember, $After$ delineates the "before" and "after" policy periods for *every panel unit*. The year effects, which capture the shocks to all communities in every year, adjust for the passage of time in the very same way.

In practice, the variables $Treat$ and $After$ are completely redundant with the fixed effects. As noted, the fixed effects already adjust for those factors in the same way. Software will more than likely drop these terms for you, and it shouldn't affect your estimate of $\beta_3$. I am partial to the latter equation; it's versatile and the policy variable can take on almost any pattern.

Comment: Hello Thomas, 
thank you for your detailed answer, this has helped me extremely in my understanding. In my case, the treatment actually affects all communities at the same time. I have calculated both "twoways" and "individual" in my regression model. However, the interaction term varies in my case. Can control variables play a role there? In other words, can modeling with time-fixed effects be necessary because of control variables? In other words, can modeling with time-fixed effects be necessary because of control variables?

Comment: Covariates can play a role. Just to be clear, in the absence of covariates, the DiD coefficients are different? They *should* be similar.

Comment: Without covariates, the estimators are identical. How do I handle the covariates? The Lagrange multiplier test is against time-fixed effect. Am I doing it right if I then only model with "individual"? Once again, thank you!

Comment: No problem. When you say *how* do you handle them, what do you mean precisely? Do you mean how do you include them? You can include a covariate as you would any other variable. As for your other concern, the model requires unit *and* time fixed effects. Are you interested in the estimates of the time dummies specifically?

Comment: Currently I use a modeling as shown in the very first equation above, supplemented by various control variables. In addition, effect = "individual" applies, which you surely know from the PLM package. So time effects are only included via `after` variable. Is that sufficient? Interest is only in the effect of the treatment, i.e., the DiD estimator. Of course, model = "within" applies.

Comment: One additional question: Could it be useful to use a "Twoways" model with regard to the control variables, although the Lagrange multiplier test shows this as not necessary?